# The tangent cone at a interior point

Tags: functional-analysis, non-smooth-analysis

Let $S$ be a subset of $X$ and $X$ is a normed space. The tangent cone to $S$ at a point $x \in S$, denoted $T_S(x)$, defined by
$$
T_S(x)=\{v:\exists \ t_k \downarrow 0, \exists\ v_k \to v \text{ such that } \ x+t_k v_{k} \in S\}
$$
and normal cone $N_{S}(x)$ is defined by
$$
N_{S}(x)=\{\xi \in X^{*}:\left<\xi,v\right>\leq 0 \ \forall v \in T_{S}(x)\}.
$$
Then can deduce that
$$
x\in \text{int} \ S \ \Longrightarrow  T_{S}(x)=X, \ N_{S}(x)=\{0\},
$$
where $\text{int} \ S$ denotes the the set of interior point of $S$.

My question is how to prove it.

Comment: It is quite trivial to prove that $T_S(x) = X$. Given $v$ you can explicitly construct the sequences $t_k$ and $v_k$.

Comment: @daw It is not easy for me. Since $x \in \text{int} \S$, then we have a open ball $B(x,r) \subset S$. It is sufficient to prove $T_S(x) \supseteq X$. If $v \in X$, how can I construct the $t_k$ and $v_k$ to deduce that $v \in T_S(x)$.

Comment: you can use $v_k :=v$

Comment: By your definition, for any nonempty set $S$ and any point $x \in S$, and for any $v \in X$, we can just take $t_k = 0, v_k = v$ for all $k$, so that $x +t_kv_k = x \in S$. So $v \in T_S(x)$. And therefore $T_S(x) = X$ always. Now I've looked up Tangent Cone to see if I could find a sensible definition, and the closest I could come to yours is the [Clarke Tangent Cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_cone#Clarke_tangent_cone), which has some differences - the most significant is that it is "for all $(t_k)$", not "there exists a $(t_k)$" as you have it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think it is not right to take $t_k=0$, since $t_k$ needs to decrease to $0$, and if takes $t_k=0$, it seems the condition of $x \in \text{int} \  S$ is redundant. Since $x \in \text{int} \  S$, then exists $\delta > 0$ such that $B(x,\delta) \subsets S$, if takes $t_k=\frac{\delta}{k\|v\|}$, then we have $x+t_k v \in S$, then we have $v \in T_{S}(v)$